# uninitialized constant Grape::Formatter::ActiveModelSerializers error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using grape gem to expose API. After deployment when running app from AWS server I am getting below error:

*Message from application: uninitialized constant Grape::Formatter::ActiveModelSerializers (NameError)*

My application is working on my ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'grape-active_model_serializers'
```

See more in https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-active_model_serializers/blob/master/README.md